# PHP - How to run a Batch File with parameters?

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd, exec

I'm developing a new portal for my business.. I have to start many batch files for different pc names.. so I try to run my batch with one parameter..

```
$path = $db->givePath($service);
        $path = $path . " " . "PCNAME"; 
        if(exec("cmd /c" . $path)){
                echo "Successful sent";
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
```

But if I run this command, nothing happens..
The old version worked:

```
$path = $db->givePath($service); 
        if(exec("cmd /c" . $path)){
                echo "Successful sent";
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
```

Can someone assist me here?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the path being returned?

Comment: services\batch.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely encountering issues when passing the PCNAME as an argument because it has characters that need to be escaped. You can read more on [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) the TL;DR is it escapes any control characters that would cause the execution to exit in an unexpected way. Using something like UNC path for PCNAME withouth using `escapshellarg()` would trick windows into thinking there was another argument being specified.

```
$path = $db->givePath($service);
$batchCmd = "C:\{$path} " . escapeshellarg('PCNAME');
if(exec("cmd /c {$batchCmd}")) {
    echo 'Successfully sent';
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Comment: and how can I use a parameter? like here: start "" "P:\ath to\batch.bat" -parameter

Comment: You are trying to provide a parameter to your batch script or you are trying to use a command line option of some kind? If you were typing something directly into the command line what would you type?

Comment: start file.bat pcname

Comment: use `escapeshellarg()`

Comment: @Dude You have been around for long enough to know you should explain and not post code only answers :-)

Comment: @blackbam I know shame on me :-( I fixed it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use cmd shell:

```
system("cmd /c C:" . $path_to_file);
```

Comment: My database returns the correct path.. If I try to run the command without parameters, it will work..

Comment: maybe you can use file with user name for example: `C:\Users\Tony\path\to\file.bat`